# How to directly access region properties from regionprops in skimage without a loop?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Once I run a command like `region = regionprops(a)`, I have to run a for loop to access properties of each region like :

```
for i in range(0,len(region)):
    if region[i].area>x and region[i].major_axis_length > y:
```

Is it possible to access these properties directly without the for loop?
For instance, `var=region.area` would create var containing area of all the regions?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `range(0, len(region))` instead of `..-1` to begin with?

Comment: We've started thinking about such an API, but have nothing implemented yet: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1343

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: Agreed. It seems silly to compute all region properties especially if looking at a video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now implemented in [`skimage.measure.regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops_table).

Comment: Isn't this just performing a for-loop in the backend?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. We do the dirty work so you don't have to. =P My interpretation of the OP's question is that they wanted a convenient method, not that they were worried about performance.

Comment: Fair enough - fair enough